# Strange datetime x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code

```
plt.stackplot(exchanges_sum.date, exchanges_sum.df1/exchanges_sum.total_supply*100, 
              exchanges_sum.df2/exchanges_sum.total_supply*100, colors=['dodgerblue', 'palevioletred'], alpha=0.7)
```

which was working find, but suddenly, i get the following chart

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Which is very strange because my data starts from 2015-09 and I have no dates before this or after 2021. Anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Do you have a categorical variable? What is the output of `exchanges_sum.dtypes`? And `exchanges_sum.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: What changed in your data between "works fine" and "works strange"? Did you read [Controlling autoscale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/autoscale.html#controlling-autoscale)?

Comment: the output is just float numbers

Comment: exchanges_sum.dtypes
Out[345]: 
date        object
balance    float64
dtype: object

Comment: {'date': {0: '12/31/2015',
  1: '12/31/2016',
  2: '12/31/2017',
  3: '12/31/2018',
  4: '12/31/2019'},
 'balance': {0: 10225889.3451,
  1: 20665893.688172024,
  2: 10479677.750309303,
  3: 16277667.852720995,
  4: 19553349.068774924}}